# How to compile driver module for older kernel?

Tags: boot, kernel, initramfs, initrd

If my local system is running version 4.4.0-88 and I want to boot a remote system using the 4.4.0-42 kernel with a driver that is only available from 4.14. How to do this? Is it possible?

I really struggle to put thought into words and appreciate every bit of help I can get.

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking "What is the relationship between initrd and vmlinux"? Is it "Can I put a driver from one kernel version into an older one" Or is it "How can I use the new scsi disk driver with kernel version 5.10"?

Comment: I just added an example, because I'm wondering if the version of the modules added to initrd matters. E.g. you add a driver to your 5.10 which is only available in 5.20.

Comment: To clarify, does the `vermagic:` from `modinfo "module"` matter?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, but I found this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238167/how-to-understand-the-modinfo-output

Comment: @TBr Yes, that answers part of my questino. I've re-written my question based on the post you sent. THanks.

Comment: Ok, I'm not an expert on this but I have no idea how you would do this even if it were possible.  And seeing that you edited your question 18 hours ago, I'm thinking that it's not a good idea even if it is possible.  That's something you would have to research and try on your own.  I will say, have a good backup handy if you find a way to do this.

Comment: I see... I want to understand which role the kernel version plays a role when it comes to drivers. Why can't I for instance take a module from 4.14 initrd and put it directly (or find it online and compile it using the old kernel)? What's the relation between the kernel version and initrd drivers? As I'm typing this this should probably be a new question.
Thank for your input, @TBr.

Comment: Well again, I'm not an expert with this, but I understand the basic concept of compatibility.  The kernel must be able to support/interface with the hardware and software.  What you are basically doing is trying to restructure the fundamental coding to work with software that it's not designed for.  At least as I see it.  Which means you need to be a developer or have that kind of baseline knowledge in order to accomplish what you are asking.  That's not a simple question you are asking here.